# Why is rails running a partial twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am calling a partial in one of my views like so:

```
<%= render :partial => 'events/attendees', :collection => @attendees %>
```

the partial however is running twice for some reason...here is the partial:

```
<% @attendees.each do |user| %>

    <li><%= link_to user.name, user %></li>

<% end %>
```

and i verified that rails is in fact running this partial twice because the output shows each item from @attendees twice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because one "loop" is from Rails (`:collection` means that Rails will render the partial for each item in the collection, in this case `@attendees`) and one loop via your own partial.

Change the partial to below (not sure about the relation between attendee/user, but here is a sample):

```
<li><%= link_to attendee.name, attendee.user %></li>
```

Or, change the call of the partial to:

```
<%= render :partial => 'events/attendees' %>
```